# Getting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException while inserting objects through hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two tables
   1) krs_question_bank
   2) krs_options

```
     CREATE TABLE krs_question_bank (
        question_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        question VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
        course_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        level_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (question_id),
        INDEX fk_krs_course_id_course_idx (course_id),
        INDEX fk_krs_level_id_level_idx (level_id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_krs_course_id_course FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES krs_course (course_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT fk_krs_level_id_level FOREIGN KEY (level_id) REFERENCES krs_level (level_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
     )
     COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
     ENGINE=InnoDB 
     ;
     CREATE TABLE krs_options (
        options_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        option VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        question_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        answer INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (options_id),
        INDEX fk_krs_question_bank_question_id_idx (question_id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_krs_question_bank_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES krs_question_bank (question_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
     )
     COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
     ENGINE=InnoDB
     ;
```

And I have two classes:
  1. Question.java
  2. Option.java

```
     package com.kr.vo;
     import java.util.List;
     import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
     import javax.persistence.Column;
     import javax.persistence.Embedded;
     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.FetchType;
     import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
     import javax.persistence.Id;
     import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
     import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
     import javax.persistence.Table;     
     @Entity
     @Table(name="krs_question_bank")
     public class Question{
         @Id
         @GeneratedValue
         @Column(name = "question_id")
         private int questionId;         
         @Column(name = "question")
         private String questionText;         
         @Column(name = "course_id")
         private int course;         
         @Column(name = "level_id")
         private int level;         
         @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
         private List<Option> options;     
     //getter and setter methods
    }

    package com.kr.vo;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="krs_options")
    public class Option{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name ="options_id")
        private int optionId;        
        @Column(name = "option")
        private String optionText;        
        @Column(name = "answer")
        private int answer;            
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="question_id", 
                    insertable=false, updatable=false, 
                    nullable=false)
        private Question question;    
        //getter and setter methods
    }
```

While I am calling session.save(Question).
  Hibernate queries are generated but..
  I am getting following error.
  Any idea how can i solve this error ?

```
 Hibernate: insert into krs_question_bank (course_id, level_id, question) values (?, ?, ?)
     Hibernate: insert into krs_options (answer, option) values (?, ?)
     Jun 10, 2017 3:54:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.kr.servlets.AddQuestion] in context with path [/MyWebApp] threw exception
     org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option) values (1, 'james')' at line 1
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
```

Comment: @Tahir Hussain Mir Query created through hibernate. I didn't write any query. When i called session.save(question); I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option** is the keyword in MYSQL server. Use different name for your table. Likewise, check all the names which are MYSQL keywords and rename them to some suitable names.

Comment: Thank you ! got the output.

Comment: my pleasure dear. ^_^ @santosh